# Confusion while installing Modem driver for ZTE MF100

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb-modem, zte

I am new to Ubuntu and use Ubuntu 14.04LTS .I wanted to install my 3G USB modem driver on my laptop from terminal.I connected the modem and extracted the file from

```
Grameenphone_Internet.tar.gz
```

After extraction I opened the file in terminal and wrote this command:

```
lsusb
```

I found this :

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05c8:0359 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4 Tech Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 19d2:0039 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0cf3:311f Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

what should i do now ? Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: What do you call "internet modem"? Is it a USB 3G/4G modem or is it a USB Wi-Fi dongle? What did you open in terminal? Why are you confused with this?

Comment: Please also [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command. It may get this clearer. Please copy text form terminal and paste it as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Is your modem connected when you run `lsusb`?

Comment: modem was not connected @Pilot6

Comment: Then this command makes no sense. Connect the modem, run this command again and replace output.

Comment: I connected the modem and then did according to your instruction,then replaced the output @Pilot6

Comment: This modem should work without installing any drivers. Does it work? And please do not add extra lines in outputs. Code can be formatted by using `{ }` button.

Comment: No it does not work @Pilot6

Comment: Did you create a connection in Network Manager? Does it show your modem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it this way. Run in terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/15-zte-MF100.rules
```

Editor will open. Paste there this text

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",SYSFS{idProduct}=="0039",SYSFS{idVendor}=="19d2",RUN+="/lib/udev/modem-modeswitch --vendor 0x12d1 --product 0x1446 --type option-zerocd"
```

Save the file, reboot the computer and plugin the modem.
It should work.